# So is everyone else

Tags: modal-verbs

Does the phrase have official term? I'd be glad to know, since that the "to be" is in an odd position.

and we usually find this scenario

> Q: They like the kittens.
>   A: So does everyone.

or

> Q: She is pretty.
>   A: So is her sister.

But how about if the sentences contain modal verbs.

> Q: We may lose the event.
>   A: So does everyone, so may everyone or so is everyone?.
>
> Q: We could lose the event.
>   A: So did everyone, so could everyone or so was everyone?.

The question is also for the rest of modal verbs, such as will, shall, might, would, should.

Comment: *Q: We may lose the event. A: So **might** everyone **else.*** To remain *elegant, consistent*, the verb after ***so*** should reflect the original verb being referred back to if it's not possible to enlist *do-support* (and auxiliaries such as *may, could* don't allow do-support). And to my mind you pretty much need *everyone **else*** for that specific context of losing  an event - I'm not sure exactly why this is, but it's to do with the fact that it's logically impossible for *everyone* to actually lose (obviously *somebody* must win! :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking how to use this phrase, or if you want to know if there is a *name* for this kind of phrase?

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer :D, hehe yeah I basically talked for a musical event or something that we were unable to see because of rain or anything that makes it logically accepted lol. So we have to use the past forms of auxiliaries right? How about if the question is with the past modal verbs such as could and might, what should we use for it?, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Andrew yes I am also looking for the name of the phrase so that I can search awhile on Google about it :)

Comment: I'm not aware of an 'official' name. "So" is one of a few words that trigger **subject-auxiliary inversion**, which explains why in your examples the auxiliary "do" precedes the subject "everyone".

Comment: @ChaesarIbrani  If there is one, FumbleFingers would know.

Comment: @Chaesar Ibrani: I never said anything about using past tense forms - not that this means anything with [defective verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb) such as *may, might, could, would*, which don't necessarily even *have* past tense forms. In this *so X everyone else* context, you should use the same tense as you would in *Everyone else X* (i.e. - third person singular, past or present according to whatever was used in the earlier statement presented by you as **Q**),

Comment: @Fumblefingers, I took the example as you used "might" instead of "may", if we have to follow the same tense and auxiliaries it will be "may" right?. Q : we may lose the event. A : so may everyone else. Or I am actually missing something?

Comment: Thanks a lot billj!, I will go for it, and I am still confused by what Fumblefinger explained, I hope you would explain me a bit simpler as I am beginner in English.

Comment: I wonder if you're looking for the word "ellipsis" to describe your examples. In "So does everyone", there is ellipsis of the complement of the supportive auxiliary verb "do". The unreduced version of your first example would be "So does everyone like the kittens".

Comment: I'm not sure I can add much more. You can say in full "So does everyone like the kittens", but that is not natural - most people would avoid unnecessary repetition by omitting "like the kittens", and simply say "So does everyone". "Does" is called a **'reduced verb phrase'** because of the **ellipsis**.

Comment: What is it that is confusing you?

Comment: @Chaesar Ibrani: Nah - I just switched to ***might*** because that's the verb I personally would use in that exact context, and to me, ***may/might*** are more or less equivalent and freely interchangeable anyway. There *are* subtle differences for me though. I think ***You may be right*** and ***That may be so*** imply significant *probability* (they'd usually occur in contexts where the speaker is in effect conceding that *he* was wrong). But ***You might be right*** almost implies *(feasibly)* to me, and ***That might be so*** just sounds a bit odd (I'd certainly never say it! :)

Answer (score 1):

The type of phrase is called a

> flattener
>   knock down

which "flattens out" or "brings down" a *(superlative)* description which usually might be prefixed with

> It's no big deal

For example

> He's really smart! *(superlative)*
>   All the kids at that school are smart. *(flattener)*
>
> She's got great legs! *(superlative)*
>   So does my horse. *(flattener)*
>
> What am I going to do? She broke up with me.
>   There are lots of fish in the ocean. *(flattener)*

Comment: Where can I get more information about that "flattener". I dont find it on Internet.

Comment: [flatten](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flatten) - to become dull or spiritless, "flattener" is the noun.

Comment: Oh,thanks.  I thought It was a particular term for that kind of phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that usage of "so" is fairly restricted in scope by convention. Personally, I definitely use it with modal verbs "will" and "can". I might occasionally use it with "could", "would", "shall", and "should", but never with "may", "might", or "must". Those are just my own personal preferences, though.

The song "Fairytale of New York" by the Pogues contains the lines:

I could have been someone.
Well, so could anyone.

It seems that "so could" is accepted in popular culture, at least.